# On Drupal 7, in a custom block, how can I find out the current page?

Tags: php, drupal

On Drupal 6, I used to have a custom PHP block which accessed arg(0), to detect which page the user was currently on. To find out whether the user was on the front page, I used:

```
if (arg(0) == '' || arg(0) == 'home') :
```

However, this test doesn't appear to work on Drupal 7, as the arg(0) returns node. I was wondering whether there is a better way to check the page - for example the template engine's $is_front which I can access at a block level to check whether the page is the front one.

Thanks for your help,

J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Drupal 7 there is a function called [drupal_is_front_page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--path.inc/function/drupal_is_front_page/7).

Also as usual you can show/hide the block from the front page simply by providing `<front>` in the list of paths in your block's configuration page.

Comment: Brilliant that is what I was looking for.  Essentially it isn't to show or not to show the page, but to dynamically change the content of the block dependent o. Page shown, thanks for the pointer, J